# Babel not working properly for ES6 import/export

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs

I am just trying to get the import/export code to work within a browser using babel-node. But so far i have only been able to get it to work with one file. I keep getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in the console which no doubt means it is not being converted with babel.

I have tried using different flags within the package.json file for running the app. As well as moving files to different folders and directories.

```
        // App.js
        const express = require('express');
        const path = require('path');

        const app = express();

        console.log('App file')

        app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html')));

        app.use('/static', express.static('src'))

        const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

        app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}.`))
```

**package.json**

```
        {
          "name": "babel-test",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "description": "",
          "main": "app.js",
          "scripts": {
            "start": "nodemon app.js src/** --exec babel-node",
            "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
          },
          "author": "AB",
          "license": "MIT",
          "dependencies": {
            "axios": "^0.18.0",
            "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
            "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
            "express": "^4.16.4",
            "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
          }
        }
```

**Folder Tree**

```
            ├── app.js
            ├── index.html
            ├── node_modules
            ├── package-lock.json
            ├── package.json
            ├── public
            └── src
                ├── index.js
                ├── script1.js
                ├── script2.js
                ├── script3.js
                └── script4.js
```

**index.html**

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">

            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
                <title>NodeJS</title>
            </head>

            <body>

                <h1>Hi there from Nodejs</h1>
                <script src="http://localhost:8000/static/script1.js"></script>
                <script src="http://localhost:8000/static/script2.js"></script>
            </body>

            </html>
```

All it needs to do is work with import and export statements between files without errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should to install and setup webpack. And then create a `webpack.config.js` file and do the configuration. https://webpack.js.org/